# How to hide php file extension and any parameters using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I trying to reach a solution to solve this problem. 
I need to every web page on my domain, to hide .php file extension and its url parameters using .htaccess file.

Example:

Currently  http://www.domain.com/page.php?id=7ca45b&n=fg&q=z981D

Expected   http://www.domain.com/page

Any help ? 
Thanks in advance

Mariano

Comment: If you want to hide the parameters, you can use `POST` instead of `GET` method. Also search for URL Rewriting.

Comment: Have you considered using clean urls?

Comment: This is a standard request if you can live with urls like `http://www.domain.com/page/7ca45b/fg/z981D` for your example above. There are _millions_ of examples for that here on StackOverflow, I suggest you read those and start yourself. Completely "hiding" the request parameters is not possible without a huge effort.

Comment: The rewriting works the other way around. You generate nice URLs in your pages and Apache's [rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (configured in `.htaccess`) internally rewrite them to standard URLs containing a lot of parameters separated by `&`. Unfortunately, there is no way to rewrite `http://www.domain.com/page` to `http://www.domain.com/page.php?id=7ca45b&n=fg&q=z981D` because there is no way to produce all those parameters out of the blue. You have to encode them somehow in your URLs. F.e. `http://www.domain.com/page/7ca45b/fg/z981D`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code in .htaccess for removing .php extension.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: 1. you have a logical error in your last statement (turn it round!) and 2. using `POST` requests instead of `GET` requests is not _that_ easy and it can cause other issues...